# Error starting pentaho BI Server in websphere 8.5 server: javax.ws.rs.Produces Class Not Found

Tags: websphere, pentaho

I'm trying to install the Pentaho BI Server 5.0.1 on a WebSphere 8.5 web application server. But I cannot start the application after deploy it.

It seems that the server can find the class `javax.ws.rs.Produces` when it is loading the `PluginAdapter`.

I checked the application lib folder and the `jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar` is present and the .class is in the JAR. I have no idea what the problem is.

Has anyone faced with a similar problem with this version or some other version of the software? Does anyone know what the problem can be?

Here is the **entire exception trace**:

> [5/12/13 14:13:59:896 CET] 000000b7 SystemOut     O 14:13:59,893 ERROR
>   [Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem:
>   org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException:
>   PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error mientras se intentaba ejecutar la
>   secuencia de arranque por
>   org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginAdapter
>   org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException:
>   org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException:
>   PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error mientras se intentaba ejecutar la
>   secuencia de arranque por
>   org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginAdapter
>       at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:306)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:269)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:182)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:136)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1678)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1374)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2179)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5384)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
>       at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
>       at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
>       at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
>       at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
>       at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:774)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
>       at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
>       at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:241)
>       at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:578)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>       at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:955)
>       at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:504)
>       at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:325)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862) Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException:
>   PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error mientras se intentaba ejecutar la
>   secuencia de arranque por
>   org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginAdapter
>       at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:372)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.access$000(PentahoSystem.java:58)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:301)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:298)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:340)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:298)
>       ... 108 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/Produces
>       at org.apache.axis2.JAXRS.JAXRSUtils.getMethodModel(JAXRSUtils.java:86)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.processMethods(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:320)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchema(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:258)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.createService(AxisService.java:2495)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.createService(AxisService.java:2452)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.webservices.AxisUtil.createService(AxisUtil.java:129)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.webservices.AxisUtil.createService(AxisUtil.java:107)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.webservices.AbstractAxisConfigurator.loadService(AbstractAxisConfigurator.java:182)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.webservices.AbstractAxisConfigurator.loadServices(AbstractAxisConfigurator.java:163)
>       at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:95)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.servicemgr.AxisWebServiceManager.initServices(AxisWebServiceManager.java:71)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.servicemgr.DefaultServiceManager.initServices(DefaultServiceManager.java:92)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.reload(DefaultPluginManager.java:225)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginAdapter.startup(PluginAdapter.java:42)
>       at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:364)
>       ... 113 more [5/12/13 14:13:59:897 CET] 000000b7 SystemOut     O 14:13:59,897 ERROR [Logger] Error end:

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere 8.5 provides its own JAX-WS classes, so there is likely a classloader conflict between its copy and your application's being loaded at the same time.

If you can just use WebSphere's by removing your copy, that might resolve things. Otherwise, search for information about changing WebSphere's classloader policy to "parent last".

Comment: Sorry. I thought that changing policy has solved my problem because the application throws another new exception. When I resolved the new exception, the old one has appeared again.

Comment: So you're not able to use the built-in JAX-WS, eh?

Comment: That's right. I tried to configure the application server and the application itself to use the 3rd party JAX-WS and I failed. I tried to use the JAX-WS WebSphere implementation and I failed. So, I don´t know what to do now. I'm sick of this problem.